# al click el elemnto no cambie, siempre selecciona el primero

Tags: javascript

como ven el boton lo hace de forma dinamica
printf(' addToCarritoItem(e,'. $e->id_productos . ')">Añadir');

aqui ese numero que viene lo coloco como parametro pero no me cambia el elemento al click del botom
function addToCarritoItem(e,id){

```
    const button=e.target
    const item = button.closest('.tr');
     //const td=document.getElementById('button').parentNode;
    // const tr=document.querySelector('td_'+id).parentNode;
    //console.log(tr)
    
    const id_prod = item.querySelector('.id_n').textContent;
  const codigo = item.querySelector('.codigo').textContent;
  const nombre = item.querySelector('.nombre').textContent;
  const cantidad_disponible = item.querySelector('.cantidad_disponible').textContent;
  const talla = item.querySelector('.talla').textContent;
  const talla_ropa = item.querySelector('.talla_ropa').textContent;
  //const itemImg = item.querySelector('.card-img-top').src;

  const Productos = {
    id: id_prod,
    codigo: codigo,
    nombre: nombre,
    cantidad_disponible: cantidad_disponible,
    talla: talla,
    talla_ropa: talla_ropa,
    precio:0,
    cantidad:1


    //img: itemImg,
      
    
  }

  let itemProductos = Productos;
  arreglo.push(itemProductos)
 

  let itemProducto =arreglo.find(({id_a}) => id_a === id);
  console.log(arreglo)
  
  let itemCarrito = carrito.find(({id_a}) => id_a === id);
  console.log(itemProducto)
    if(itemCarrito){
       //console.log("Producto ya existe en carrito");
      if (itemProducto.cantidad_disponible<=itemProducto.cantidad){
        return;
      }
      console.log("Repetido");
     itemProducto.cantidad++;
     const a= document.getElementsByClassName('PRE').textContent=itemProducto.cantidad
     console.log(a)
     //document.querySelector("PRE_"+id).value=itemProducto.cantidad;
    }
    else{
      console.log("NO Repetido");
      itemCarrito = structuredClone(itemProducto); //creamos un clon para agregarlo al carrito
     itemCarrito.cantidad=1
     itemCarrito.precio
      carrito.push(itemCarrito);
      
      //renderiza (agrega) un producto a la tabla de carrito
      carrito_content.innerHTML+= interpolate(templateRowCarrito.innerHTML,itemCarrito);
    }
    
  
   //updatecantidad(id,itemCarrito.cantidad);
  }
```

como se puede apreciar en mi ejemplo minimo veriflicqble esque siempre muestra solo un producto es decir el primero , necesito que el elemento se agregue al cambie acorde al boton o la cantidad aumente, los productos los traigo de php hacia mi tabla productos y la tabla proctos se llena automaticamente por eso elegi javascript para hacer el carrito, puse en el ejemplo un 15 ya que esa es la relidad toma el 15 es decir el primero y de hay no pasa }
**QUIERO QUE CAMBIE a medida que se selecciona otro elemento**
porfavor ayuda en la implementacion de este caso
los leo

```js
const Clickbutton = document.querySelectorAll('#articulos > tbody > tr > .td > .button')


Clickbutton.forEach(btn => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', addToCarritoItem)
})
  let carrito = []
  var arreglo=[]   
  
  //función para convertir un template con variables --> https://medium.com/@mrg101/this-is-great-thinking-2153c8982152
  function interpolate(template, params) {
    template = template.toString().trim()
    const replaceTags = { '&': '&amp;', '<': '&lt;', '>': '&gt;', '(': '%28', ')': '%29' };
    const safeInnerHTML = text => text.toString().replace(/[&<>\(\)]/g, tag => replaceTags[tag] || tag);
    const keys = Object.keys(params);
    const keyVals = Object.values(params).map(safeInnerHTML);
    return new Function(...keys, `return \`${template}\``)(...keyVals);
   }
   
   
   function addToCarritoItem(e,id){
  
    

    const button=e.target
    const item = button.closest('tr')
    
   const id_n = item.querySelector('.id_n').textContent
    const id_prod = item.querySelector('.id_prod').textContent
  const codigo = item.querySelector('.codigo').textContent
   const nombre = item.querySelector('.nombre').textContent
 const cantidad_disponible = item.querySelector('.CantidadDisponible').textContent
  
 
const Productos = {
    id: id_prod,
    codigo: codigo,
   nmbre:nombre,
    cantidad_disponible: cantidad_disponible,
   
    precio:0,
    cantidad:1


    //img: itemImg,
      
    
  }

  let itemProductos = Productos;
  arreglo.push(itemProductos)
 

  let itemProducto =arreglo.find(({id_a}) => id_a === id);
  console.log(arreglo)
  
  let itemCarrito = carrito.find(({id_a}) => id_a === id);
  console.log(itemProducto)
    if(itemCarrito){
       //console.log("Producto ya existe en carrito");
      if (itemProducto.cantidad_disponible<=itemProducto.cantidad){
        return;
      }
      console.log("Repetido");
     itemProducto.cantidad++;
     const a= document.getElementsByClassName('PRE').textContent=itemProducto.cantidad
     console.log(a)
     //document.querySelector("PRE_"+id).value=itemProducto.cantidad;
    }
    else{
      console.log("NO Repetido");
      itemCarrito = structuredClone(itemProducto); //creamos un clon para agregarlo al carrito
     itemCarrito.cantidad=1
     itemCarrito.precio
      carrito.push(itemCarrito);
      
      //renderiza (agrega) un producto a la tabla de carrito
      carrito_content.innerHTML+= interpolate(templateRowCarrito.innerHTML,itemCarrito);
    }
    
  
   //updatecantidad(id,itemCarrito.cantidad);
  }
  

  
  
   //updatecantidad(id,itemCarrito.cantidad);
  
//updatecantidad(id,itemCarrito.cantidad);
```

```html
<template id="templateRowCarrito">
 <tr id="C_${id}">
 
  
  <td><input type="number" value="${cantidad}" class="PRE" id="PRE_${id}"  min="0"></td>
  <td><input type="number" value="${precio}"  min="0"></td>
  <td id="T_${id}"></td>
 </tr>
</template> 
            

      <table id="articulos"class="table">
        <thead>
           
            <tr>
            
            <TH>id </TH>
            <TH>id del producto</TH>
                <TH>Codigo</TH>
              <TH>Nombre</TH>
                <TH>cantidad_disponible</TH>
                <TH>Añadir</TH>
             
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody  id="productos_content">
        <tr>
    <td class="id_n">15</td>
                <td class="id_prod">15</td>
                <td class="codigo">EAN_00001</td>
               <td class="nombre">Nike Force 1</td>
                <td class="CantidadDisponible"> 4</td>
                 <td class="td"><button  class="button" onclick="(e)=> addToCarritoItem(e,15)">Añadir</button></td>
   
   </tr>
   
   
   <tr>
    <td class="id_n">16</td>
                <td class="id_prod">16</td>
                <td class="codigo">EAN_00002</td>
               <td class="nombre">Nike</td>
                <td class="CantidadDisponible"> 10</td>
                 <td class="td"><button  class="button" onclick="(e)=> addToCarritoItem(e,15)">Añadir</button></td>
   
   </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    
      </div>




      

   

      <table id="tabla" class="table">
        
           
            <tr>
            <TH>Cantidad</TH>
                <TH>Precio</TH>
                
              
               
               
            </tr>
               <tbody id="carrito_content" class="tbody">
               
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Para preguntar en stackoverflow ingles